# Grub not working after Windows 8.1 update on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I do understand that this is a common problem, and I have read few of the threads. Here is synopsis of my problem.

Logged on to window 8.1, windows installed updates and now grub2 doesn't work

- Laptop is a Toshiba C55-A
- Secure boot is disable
- Turn off fast startup
- booted with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Live CD
- by pressing c accessed grub prompt
- exited out of grub at which point was able to access boot manager
  with Windows Boot Manager, Ubuntu, Ubuntu options
- Selected Ubuntu
- Booted into Ubuntu
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
- Selected recommended repair
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7743525/
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7760191/

The output on boot tab from msconfig (windows command prompt) shows only windows 8.1

The output from the bcdedit is as follows

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
detecthal               Yes
```

Did not see the grub2 menu as expected?

Any other ideas

**References**

- [Restore backup of WinEFI or UEFI (not sure) that boot-repair made](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377252/restore-backup-of-winefi-or-uefi-not-sure-that-boot-repair-made)
- [Unable to run Ubuntu 12.04 without USB flash drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147313/unable-to-run-ubuntu-12-04-without-usb-flash-drive)
- [Recovering Grub after installing windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370910/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-8-1)
- [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Comment: @bain, thank you for the link which helped arriving at a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too. After updating to Win 8.1, installing boot-repair in ubuntu & running it didn't work for me. (But it was working earlier. Also note that I have to use boot-repair disk after every windows update - every month - since updating to windows 8.1. Before that this problem was not there)

Instead create a bootable usb with boot-repair.

Download iso here: [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

Boot into this & select recommended repair. It will solve the problem.

Comment: I ran the boot repair, but it did not make any changes. I ran it from Ubuntu not from a disk or usb drive

Comment: No, thats what I said in the answer. Running it from usb instead of installing it in ubuntu solved the problem for me. Create bootable usb and run it.

Comment: Thank you for your input, which help me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following are set of steps to get Grub working after windows 8.1 update on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

- Boot computer using live Ubuntu CD and choose "Try Ubuntu"
- Open a xterm and type the following commands

  > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  >
  > sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-**precise**.list
  >
  > sudo apt-get update
  >
  > sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
- In boot-repair select the advance options
- Select the Grub options tab. **Secure boot need to be unchecked** and press apply
- Following commands will pop up on a screen. Copy them to terminal and execute the commands.

  > sudo dpkg --configure -a
  >
  > sudo apt-get install -fy
  >
  > sudo apt-get purge -y-force-yes grub* shim-signed
- Press forward

  > sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-efi
- Press forward

With the above steps grub was re installed.

**References**

- [SecureBoot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot)
- [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Advanced_options)
- [Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in 10 easy steps (Section 7)](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)
- [How to install Grub from a live Ubuntu cd.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=224351)
- [How to Repair GRUB2 When Ubuntu Won’t Boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)
- [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)